# Installing older version of Apple apps

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have two versions of my app in the AppStore.
Version 1 and Version 1.1

- Version 1 is a iPad-only app supporting only iOS 6 and up.
- Version 1.1 is a universal app supporting iOS 5 thru 7.

I have a user that REALLY want's to use version 1 of the app (for specific reasons), can he now download that version instead of the latest release?

I know Apple claims to allow the download of older versions, but I have a stinky feeling that Apple also applies their own conditional logic to this feature: i.e. Only allow the download of an older version if the newer version is not supported by the user's current iOS.

I hope I'm wrong, but on my iPad there is no option to download version 1 in the AppStore.

PS. My itunesconnect setup is correct as follows:
[image http://imageshack.com/scaled/medium/818/u635.png](http://imageshack.com/scaled/medium/818/u635.png)

Comment: For what I've understand of this, the user will only see the last compatible version for his iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Apple will only offer to download an older version of your app if the new is not longer supporting the user iOS version.

Lest say user 1 is on iOS 5 and can upgrade, you new version is only available on 6 and 7. Them the user will be prompted with the option to download the previous version.

Users cannot choose the version to download themselves.

Comment: So, regardless of all the many reasons developers might have to make older versions available and all the flexibility such an option might add, Apple supports it ONLY for device/iOS-version compatibility issues? How short-sighted of them. How typically Apple :-)

Comment: Well yes and no, there could be a real issue (lest say API change) why previous versions should not longer work. Apple just make sure you as a developers will not mis a sale because your latest version does not support the users iOS version any more. They will soon allow you to specify which version can be installed on older version of iOS.

Comment: As far as I know, only users who have already purchased / downloaded  your app before are able to download previous versions if their device / iOS version does not support the current release.

Comment: @Horst from what I can see, that is still the case. Unless I'm missing something.